# can I limit consumption of kafka-node consumer?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

It seems like my kafka node consumer:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var consumer = new Consumer(client, [], {
     ...
    });
```

is fetching way too many messages than I can handle in certain cases. 
Is there a way to limit it (for example accept no more than 1000 messages per second, possibly using the pause api?)

- I'm using kafka-node, which seems to have a limited api comparing to the Java version

Answer (score 5):

In Kafka, poll and process should happen in a coordinated/synchronized way. Ie, after each poll, you should process all received data first, before you do the next poll. This pattern will automatically throttle the number of messages to the max throughput your client can handle.

Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
while(isRunning) {
  messages = poll(...)
  for(m : messages) {
    process(m);
  }
}
```

(That is the reason, why there is not parameter "fetch.max.messages" -- you just do not need it.)

Comment: Do you know of a similar api in node-kafka module?

Comment: I personally do not use node.js. Furthermore, there are multiple client implementations available -- I assume, that the "correct code" depends on the library you are using: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients#Clients-Node.js

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar situation where I was consuming messages from Kafka and had to throttle the consumption because my consumer service was dependent on a third party API which had its own constraints.

I used `async/queue` along with a wrapper of `async/cargo` called `asyncTimedCargo` for batching purpose. 
The cargo gets all the messages from the kafka-consumer and sends it to queue upon reaching a size limit `batch_config.batch_size` or timeout `batch_config.batch_timeout`. 
`async/queue` provides `saturated` and `unsaturated` callbacks which you can use to stop the consumption if your queue task workers are busy. This would stop the cargo from filling up and your app would not run out of memory. The consumption would resume upon unsaturation.

```
//cargo-service.js
module.exports = function(key){
    return new asyncTimedCargo(function(tasks, callback) {
        var length = tasks.length;
        var postBody = [];
        for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
            var message ={};
            var task = JSON.parse(tasks[i].value);
            message = task;
            postBody.push(message);
        }
        var postJson = {
            "json": {"request":postBody}
        };
        sms_queue.push(postJson);
        callback();
    }, batch_config.batch_size, batch_config.batch_timeout)
};

//kafka-consumer.js
cargo = cargo-service()
consumer.on('message', function (message) {
    if(message && message.value && utils.isValidJsonString(message.value)) {
        var msgObject = JSON.parse(message.value);        
        cargo.push(message);
    }
    else {
        logger.error('Invalid JSON Message');
    }
});

// sms-queue.js
var sms_queue = queue(
retryable({
    times: queue_config.num_retries,
    errorFilter: function (err) {
        logger.info("inside retry");
        console.log(err);
        if (err) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}, function (task, callback) {
// your worker task for queue
  callback()
}), queue_config.queue_worker_threads);

sms_queue.saturated = function() {
    consumer.pause();
    logger.warn('Queue saturated Consumption paused: ' + sms_queue.running());
};
sms_queue.unsaturated = function() {
    consumer.resume();
    logger.info('Queue unsaturated Consumption resumed: ' + sms_queue.running());
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From [FAQ](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node#how-to-throttle-messages--control-the-concurrency-of-processing-messages) in the README

1. Create a `async.queue` with message processor and concurrency of one (the message processor itself is wrapped with `setImmediate` function so it will not freeze up the event loop)
2. Set the `queue.drain` to `resume()` the consumer
3. The handler for consumer's message event to `pause()` the consumer and pushes the message to the queue.

Comment: This is interesting, but I couldn't find any example of this being implemented. Is there any sample code for this. I am not sure how to initialize consumer with this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the API does not have any kind of throttling. But both consumers (Consumer and HighLevelConsumer) have a 'pause()' function. So you could stop consuming if you get to much messages. Maybe that already offers what you need.

Please keep in mind what's happening. You send a fetch request to the broker and get a batch of message back. You can configure the min and max size of the messages (according to the documentation not the number of messages) you want to fetch:

```
{
    ....
    // This is the minimum number of bytes of messages that must be available to give a response, default 1 byte 
    fetchMinBytes: 1,

    // The maximum bytes to include in the message set for this partition. This helps bound the size of the response. 
     fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024,
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, initially fetchMaxBytes value was

```
fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024 * 10 // 10MB
```

I just chanbed it to

```
fetchMaxBytes: 1024
```

It worked very smoothly after the change.